# How can I add a new event from the front end to a solspace calendar event field added to the user profile

Tags: craft3, plugin-solspacecalendar

I am trying to add a new event from the front end to a solspace calendar event field I added to the user profile.

I created a calendar event field then added it to the user profiles.  I can add an event directly from the craft admin page but I am trying to add a new event to the current user when I submit a form.

Comment: Here's the documentation for frontend forms: https://docs.solspace.com/craft/calendar/v3/templating-extras/events-front-end.html#example-code-from-demo-templates Have you tried that? Any specific problems you're running into?

Comment: Yes I have tried looking at this template. This does allow me to update and edit the current event but I still can not figure out how to add this to the specific users calendar event field.  I can not figure out exactly what to add to the form to add the specific event to the event field in the current user.  documentation is lacking information about the calendar event fields